# Why can't `each` access the first element?

Tags: ruby, iterator, each

When I do this, it does not access `array[0]`:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.each {|x| puts "Position: #{x}, Orig: #{array[x]}, Mod: #{array[x] + 3}" }
```

Result:

```
Position: 1, Orig: 2, Mod: 5
Position: 2, Orig: 3, Mod: 6
Position: 3, Orig: 4, Mod: 7
Position: 4, Orig: 5, Mod: 8
```

Why doesn't `each` access position `0`?

Comment: Also remember that there is and `each_with_index{|entry,index|} ` function. This would have helped a lot to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that actually the output you're getting?  This is what I'm seeing:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.each {|x| puts "Position: #{x}, Orig: #{array[x]}, Mod: #{array[x] + 3}" }
```

result:

```
Position: 1, Orig: 2, Mod: 5
Position: 2, Orig: 3, Mod: 6
Position: 3, Orig: 4, Mod: 7
Position: 4, Orig: 5, Mod: 8
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):2:in `each'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/amitgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in `<main>
```

When you say `array.each { |x| ... }`, that `x` is not going to iterate over the indices of elements in `array`, it'll iterate over the elements themselves.  The 0th element is `1`, `array[1]` is `2`, and `array[1]+3` is `2+3` which is `5`.  The last element is `5`, `array[5]` is `nil` because `array` only has 5 elements and in Ruby, arrays are 0-based indexed, and then `array[5] + 3` is `nil + 3` which gives you the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Ah yes I should've picked a different set of numbers for my test case, I see the issue now! Thank you for the response. Back to scratching my head over blocks. Is the first version of my_each accurate to each's implementation?

Comment: It looks like most of your original question has been edited out to just focus on the misunderstanding about `array[0]`.  Now that that's out of the way, go back and test if your `my_each` works as expected.  From what I recall, it looked right.  If not, feel free to open up a new question thread.

Comment: I think I've cleared up the confusion in my head. I was assuming that `x` was holding the element reference, rather than its value. On top of that my unfortunate selection of [1,2,3,4,5] as my test array had me thinking the 0th place was never accessed, when in fact it was showing the value, not the index. I've spent the last few hours making steady headway now, re-implementing many more methods just using their description from the Ruby doc pages. Thanks to you and to whoever boiled down the original question to the crux of the issue.